# Store ObservableCollection Items globally

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an application that allows users to populate a list. I am using ObservableCollection for my List. This works fine but I need to reference these list of items from another method and later on in other classes. How can I pass these list of items such that it can be accessed globally? Below is my code and my attempt at achieving this, any help will be appreciated.

**CODE: This method populates my list**

```
 public ObservableCollection<Products> products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Products>();

public void LoadItems()
        {
            products.Add(new Products { ProductActivity = UserActivity.Text, ProductHours = ActivityHrs.Text + "Hrs" });
            MyListView.ItemsSource = products;
        }
```

**MY STATIC CLASS(I created this class to try to pass the "products" object in the above method  to my static ObservableCollection but this doesn't seem to work)**

```
  public static class MyStatic
    {
        static MyStatic()
        {
            ActivityList = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
        }
        public static ObservableCollection<Products> ActivityList { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is actually the Singleton pattern, which  allows you to create and use exactly one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static ObservableCollection<Products> products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
```

Add the static keyword. no need for the second code snippet you provided.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't expect it to be as simple as that, managed to access it in my other class also by the use of parameters! :)